# Dealing with two select lists that are equal

Tags: watir, watir-webdriver

I have two select list that are equal how do i access the second one?

I have put a value on the first one but when putting a value to the second it goes to the first.

Anyone can help me.

```
<div id="selectNumber">
  <select id="numbers" name="numbers" tabindex="5" onchange="changeNumbers(this);">
    <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="all">25</option>
    <option value="123">26</option>
    <option value="124">27</option>
  </select>
<a onclick="addRemoveSelectedNumber(this);">
  <img src="../../static/images/delete.png">
</a>
</div>
<div id="selectNumber">
  <select id="numbers" name="numbers" tabindex="5" onchange="changeNumbers(this);">
     <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
     <option value="all">25</option>
     <option value="123">26</option>
     <option value="124">27</option>
  </select>
<a onclick="addRemoveSelectedNumber(this);">
  <img src="../../static/images/delete.png">
</a>
```

Tanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will select *25* from the second select list:

```
browser.select_list(:id => "numbers", :index => 1).select "25"
```

More information: *Multiple Attributes* chapter at https://github.com/zeljkofilipin/watirbook/blob/master/link.md

By the way, you should report a bug that there are multiple instances of HTML elements with the same `id` on the page.  Per the HTML standard, ID values should be unique

Comment: It worked fine so the index is select list number?  Tanks i will do that

Comment: Yes, index is the number of the select list. Please note that the first select list will have the number 0.

Comment: See also: what happens when your development team doesn't understand the benefits of scripted testing.  Show them the way, and they'll start giving you relevant attributes (maybe).

Comment: I don't have a lot of hope for his development team.  The idea that ID values are supposed to be unique on a page has been around since HTML v1.0  That they do not even comprehend this essential, simple, basic aspect of the HTML standard, and/or are willing to violate the standard with no apparent concern fills me with nothing but despair (or is that disdain?  or perhaps both..)